# Given an undirected graph, find the number of ways to remove edges to make all vertices even degree

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations

You're given an undirected graph **G** with **E** number of edges. You're allowed to remove edges as much as you like to make all the vertices in the graph have an even degree. The task is to find the number of ways we can achieve this. All disconnected graph is also a valid solution. I'm struggling to find an algorithm to find the ways without brute-force. Any direction is appreciated.

Edit:
The order in which edges are selected to be removed doesn't matter. The goal is to find the number of ways to select the set of edges to remove.

Edit:
A graph without all edges is also a valid way and should be counted.

Comment: Does the order in which edges are removed count? I mean, removing first some edge $(a, b)$ and then $(c, d)$ should be the same as first removing $(c, d)$ and then $(a,b)$, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the order doesn't matter. The number of ways to select the set of edges to remove is the goal. I'll update the question.

Comment: One more question: Do we want the degrees of the resulting graph to be as close as possible to the degrees of the original graph? For example, for any graph, by removing all edges, we get a graph that satisfies the evenness condition. Should we always count this as one the ways to get an all-even-degree graph?

Comment: Graph without all edges is also a valid way. It doesn't need to be close to the original graph

Comment: The goal is to find the ways to remove edges to make all the vertices even degree. Even though the graph is already have even degree vertices, still we need to exploit other possible graphs by removing edges. i.e. We don't need to get it to an even degree vertex state, but rather find how many such states are possible by removing edges.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=(V,E)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is the set of edges.

Let $A$ be the $|V|\times|E|$ matrix such that for each $e=\{u,v\}\in E$ we have $A_{u,e}=A_{v,e}=1$, and all the remaining elements of $A$ are zero. Then, if we identify a subgraph (obtained after removing edges) by a map $x : E\to\{0,1\}, e\mapsto x_e$, with $x_e$ indicating the *presence* of $e$, then the degree of a vertex $v\in V$ in this subgraph is $\sum_{e\in E}A_{v,e}x_e$.

If we consider $A$ as a matrix over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$, and $x$ as a column vector (over $\mathbb{F}_2$), then all the degrees are even if and only if $Ax=0$ (in $\mathbb{F}_2$). So we are facing the problem of computing the kernel of $A$ (the number of solutions $x$ is equal to $2^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the kernel).

Here, any suitable kernel-finding method will do.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Would it be possible to illustrate the solution with a small example if you have the time?